# Use Spark SQL JDBC Server/Beeline or spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark SQL, there are two options to submit sql.

1. `spark-sql`, for each sql, it will kick off a new Spark application.
2. `Spark JDBC Server and Beeline`, The Jdbc Server is actually a long running standalone spark application, and the sqls submitted to it will share the resources

We are having about 30 big sql queries,each would like to occupy 200 cores and 800G memory to finish in reasonable time(30 mins).

As of `spark-sql and jdbc server/beeline`, which option is better for my case?
To me, I would like to use `spark-sql`, and I have no idea how many resources should be given to jdbc server to make my queries to finish in reasonable time.

If I can submit the 30 queries to Jdbc Server, then how many resources(cores/memory) that this Jdbc Server should be given(5000+ cores and 10T+ memory?)?

Comment: Does each query work on different tables/RDDs ? 800 G of memory is used for caching tables ?

Comment: @AjaySrivastava， some of the tables are cached，since we are using 200 executors, each given 4G memory.